# click on link remove href from the next links so, i can't vote again

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/hNpmc/

just need some help with this little problem,
for instance if i vote on apple i want to disable all the links after apple, this script somehow is working but it dose not work like the way i want, however i am still learning  jQuery, so i don't have enough experience about it

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#container .bar a").click(function() {

            var target = $(this);

            target.html('Voted').addClass('voted');

            //$('span a').removeAttr('href'); // this doese not help



            return false;
        });
});

</script>




<div id="container"> 


<span id="question">What is your favorite</span>



 <div class="bar"><span> 10% </span><span><a class="a" href="">Vote</a></span> apple</div>
 <div class="bar"><span> 20% </span><span><a class="a" href="">Vote</a></span> banana</div>
 <div class="bar"><span> 30% </span><span><a class="a" href="">Vote</a></span> lemon</div>


</div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: What do you mean in "disable"?

Comment: A bit late in getting the clarification as I have already provided an answer. But better late than never. By *want to disable all the links after apple* do you mean that if I vote for apple, all three vote links should be disabled?

Comment: i just don't know how to do that...

Comment: @mohamedfathi, if you vote on banana then only lemone link will be disable or apple link will also disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all links but have the 'Voted' text only for the `<a>` that was clicked, modify your code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container .bar a").click(function () {
        var target = $("#container .bar a");
        $(this).html('Voted').addClass('voted');
        target.removeAttr('href').off('click');
        return false;
    });
});
```

`$(this)` points to the `<a>` that was clicked and hence the text change is done only for that. `target = $("#container .bar a");` will mean that all such `<a>` elements are selected and `off('click')` will disable the `click` event on all of them.

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9Y92J/1/)

Comment: :) but now you are applying voted to all links which i dont want

Comment: are you saying you want all links to be disabled but show "voted" only for the link that was clicked?

Comment: @mohamedfathi: I have updated the answer and the demo link. Try it

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#container .bar a").click(function() {

            var target = $(this);

            // disabling all next a links
            var allNext = target.parents('.bar').nextAll().css("opacity",0.5);                                                                
            allNext.find("a").removeAttr("href").off("click mouseover mouseenter");                                

            $(this).addClass('voted').html('Voted');                
            $(this).removeAttr('href');                        

            return false;
        });
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hNpmc/4/